# Slant table text same as we get in Text-Orientation in MS Excel

Tags: html, css

I want to create **slanted** headers for my HTML table as in the screenshot of Excel below. Is there any way to achieve this design using CSS

[image: excel representation of Text Oriented design]

I tried using Flex
My HTML Code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container > * {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="matrix-column">
    Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="matrix-column">
    Column 2
  </div>
  <div class="matrix-column">
    Column 3
  </div>
  <div class="matrix-column">
    Column 4
  </div>
  <div class="matrix-column">
    Column 5
  </div>
  <div class="matrix-column">
    Column 6
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/a-arora/pen/QWBWvxK

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: You should post your html code too.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with including an example of your code within your question.

Comment: I added my css. But ya missed the HTML. Added the codepen link. Hope that helps

Comment: Please place your code within your question, not on an external site (the reason for this is that SO is not just trying to help you, but it is trying to build up a repository of questions and answers that will be useful to future readers). Also, are you trying to create an HTML table or another layout?

Comment: Yes, HTML Table basically but using divs. Not by `<table>`

Comment: So is the problem just that the border lines are not in the same sort of place as they would be in Excel? (ie going to the top of the containing element)

Comment: Check this CSS-Tricks article: https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/ . This CodePen might also help: https://codepen.io/peterfarrell/pen/yNPrXB

Comment: @AHaworth yes. The whole div gets rotated when using transform.

Comment: @BumhanYu Thanks man! This is exactly what I needed. Please add it as answer so that I can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two online resources that point to the solutions.

#### Use `transform: rotate()` and `translate()`

`rotate()` to angle the headers and `translate()` to adjust the positioning. Original article can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/rotated-table-column-headers/).

Snippet below:

```css
.table-header-rotated {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.csstransforms .table-header-rotated td {
  width: 30px;
}
.no-csstransforms .table-header-rotated th {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table-header-rotated td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.csstransforms .table-header-rotated th.rotate {
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.csstransforms .table-header-rotated th.rotate > div {
  transform: translate(25px, 51px) rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}
.csstransforms .table-header-rotated th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table-header-rotated th.row-header {
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/modernizr-2.7.1.js"></script>
<table class="table table-header-rotated">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- First column header is not rotated -->
      <th></th>
      <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
      <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 1</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 2</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 3</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 4</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 5</span></div></th>
        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Column header 6</span></div></th>
    </tr> 
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 1</th>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row1-column1"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row1-column2"></td>
      <td><input name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row1-column3"></td>
      <td><input name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row1-column4"></td>
      <td><input name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row1-column5"></td>
      <td><input name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row1-column6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 2</th>
      <td><input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row2-column1"></td>
      <td><input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row2-column2"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row2-column3"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row2-column4"></td>
      <td><input name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row2-column5"></td>
      <td><input name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row2-column6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row-header">Row header 3</th>
      <td><input name="column1[]" type="radio" value="row3-column1"></td>
      <td><input name="column2[]" type="radio" value="row3-column2"></td>
      <td><input name="column3[]" type="radio" value="row3-column3"></td>
      <td><input name="column4[]" type="radio" value="row3-column4"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column5[]" type="radio" value="row3-column5"></td>
      <td><input checked="checked" name="column6[]" type="radio" value="row3-column6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Use `transform: rotate()` and `skew()`

Similar to above, but use `skew` to adjust positioning. See the original Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/peterfarrell/pen/yNPrXB).

Snippet below:

```css
.table-header-rotated th.rotate-45 {
  height: 160px;
  width: 40px;
  min-width: 40px;
  max-width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 0.8;
}

.table-header-rotated th.rotate-45>div {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: -80px;
  /* 80 * tan(45) / 2 = 40 where 80 is the height on the cell and 45 is the transform angle*/
  height: 100%;
  transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-header-rotated th.rotate-45 span {
  transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 120px;
  /* 40 cos(45) = 28 with an additional 2px margin*/
  left: -25px;
  /*Because it looked good, but there is probably a mathematical link here as well*/
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  width: 85px;
  /* 80 / cos(45) - 40 cos (45) = 85 where 80 is the height of the cell, 40 the width of the cell and 45 the transform angle*/
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*whether to display in one line or not*/
}

.table-striped-column>thead>tr th:nth-of-type(even) div {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.table-striped-column>tbody>tr td:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<body style="padding:50px;">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h2>Assignments for Day 1</h2>
      <h4 class="muted">Class #684</h4>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-header-rotated table-striped table-hover table-striped-column">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="row-header">Trainee</th>
          <!-- Following headers are rotated -->
          <th class="rotate-45">
            <div><span>Learning Styles Assessment</span></div>
          </th>
          <th class="rotate-45">
            <div><span>Video #2 - Company Value & Goals</span></div>
          </th>
          <th class="rotate-45">
            <div><span>Video #3 - The Technician Job</span></div>
          </th>
          <th class="rotate-45">
            <div><span>Vidoe #5 - Custom Service</span></div>
          </th>
          <th class="rotate-45">
            <div><span>Safety Awareness Questionnaire</span></div>
          </th>
          <th class="rotate-45">
            <div><span>Video #8 - Muscular Injury Prevention</span></div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Obama, Barak</td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Regan, Ronald</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Washington, George</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><span class="label label-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i></span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```